# coproduct of cyclic groups

Tags: finite-groups, cyclic-groups

there is no coproduct of two cyclic groups of order 3 in the category of finite groups.

This is the statement I believe it is true. However I do not know how to verify this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Free product of two nontrivial groups is always infinite. This follows immediately from description of free product in terms of reduced words.